# Converting native point datatype into Geometry(Point,4326) using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql, geometry, psycopg2

I have a table with "coordinate" column in it of data_type POINT (native postrgresql point). I want to convert it into Geometry(Point,4326)

I am using psycopg2 to connect to my database.

I ran this command:

`cur.execute(f"ALTER TABLE {table} ALTER COLUMN {column} TYPE geometry(Point, 4326) USING ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint({column}[0],{column}[1]), 4326);")`

But it gives this error:

```
server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request
```

and if I use

`cur.execute(f"ALTER TABLE {table} ALTER COLUMN {column} TYPE geometry(Point, 4326) USING {column}::ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint({column}[0],{column}[1]), 4326);")`

it says `st_setsrid does not exist.`

If I cannot solve this issue, is there any other way to convert dataType of column from native point to geometry(point,4326)?

Comment: Do you have PostGIS extension installed into your database? Check with `select postgis_version();`.

Comment: Yes, postgis was installed.
select postgis_version()  --> 2.1 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1

Comment: what tool do you use to execute your request ? Maybe try to create your table first check if it's good then go with a insert into request ... baby steps =)

Comment: Does simple `select ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1,2), 4326)` work? If is works then perhaps `{column}[0],{column}[1]` are not of correct datatype for ST_MakePoint.

Comment: I ran this command : `SELECT GeometryType(ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint({column}[0],{column}[1]),4326)) FROM {table} LIMIT 5`
And it is working give "point" as result

Comment: Is there any better success if you add a new column and update it with the same SQL body?

Comment: yeah adding new column is working

Comment: FWIW: your second statement is syntactically wrong: there is no `CAST` to `ST_SetSRID` - you need to wrap the actual `CAST` into those functions, i.e. `USING ST_SetSRID(<column>::GEOMETRY(POINT), 4326)`

Comment: it also give this error 
server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(@[geozelot](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/93656/geozelot)) Right way to type cast is -

`cur.execute(f"ALTER TABLE {table} ALTER COLUMN {column} TYPE geometry(Point,4326) USING ST_SetSRID({column}::GEOMETRY(POINT), 4326);")`